# Extjs child item not filling the parent container

Tags: layout, extjs

My problem is, even if I used "layout: 'fit'" in all my children items within a boarder layout, they just shrinks into a small box rather than fill the parent, as described in fit layout.

I want the EDS.view.selector.Container to fill the "navigation" section of my boarder layout.

```
(Code excerpt)

Ext.define('EDS.view.selector.Container', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.selectorcontainer',

    layout: 'fit',
    initComponent: function(){
         this.items = [
                {
                    xtype: 'tabpanel',
                    defaults: {
                        bodyPadding: 10
                    },
                    layout: 'fit',
                    items:[
                         {
                             title: 'Organization',
                             id: 'selector-organization',
                             tag: 'div',                             
                             html: 'div here',
                             height: '100%',
                         }                  
                    ]
                }
        ],
        this.callParent();
    },
});



(Controller)
init: function(){
    console.log('controller.init()');

    new Ext.Viewport({
        title: 'Data Analysis',
        layout: 'border',
        defaults: {
                collapsible: true,
                split: true,
                bodyStyle: 'padding: 15px',
        },
        items: [{
            title: 'Navigation',
            region:'west',
            margins: '5 0 0 0',
            cmargins: '5 5 0 0',
            width: 600,
            minSize: 100,
            maxSize: 250,
                items: [
                    {
                    id: 'selector-container',
                        xtype: 'selectorcontainer',
                        layout: 'fit',
                    }
            ]
        },{
            title: 'Main Content',
            collapsible: false,
            region:'center',
            margins: '5 0 0 0'
        }]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not set up layout for wrapper containers in your border layout:

```
items: [{
    title: 'Navigation',
    region:'west',
    layout: 'fit',
    ...
    items: [

            ]
    },{
    title: 'Main Content',
    collapsible: false,
    region:'center',
    layout: 'fit',
    ...
}]
```

Remember: In ExtJS any plain JS object that goes into `items` property of a container will be converted into some type of Ext component with `xtype` defined by `defaultType` property of that container. In most cases it will be `panel`.

Comment: Thanks. I think the mistake I had is to set the 'fit layout' for child element rather than the parent container.

Comment: Pretty much, yes. Actually you could put your `selectorcontainer` directly into one of the regions without wrapping container.